# How to use document.evaluate and XPathResult with IE 11?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I use this javascript on chrome and PhantomJS (is OK) but on IE 11 is KO(XPathResult is undefined)

```
document.evaluate(".//*[@name=\'smilejs\' and @title=\'smilejs\']", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.click();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

IE does not support Xpath. See the [browser compatibility list on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate#Browser_compatibility).
You can use jQuery or another lib like [Wicked Good XPath](https://github.com/google/wicked-good-xpath) as workaround.